# jQuery DataTables doesn't display rows that has null columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, datatables

I want to display the rows that has null columns. I'm trying to put with "defaultContent": '' but it doesn't work.

This is my datatable code:

```
var table = $('#tablaCliente').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": "5%",
        "targets": [0]
    },
    {
        "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",
        "targets": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }, ],
    "language":
    {
        "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":
    {
        "url": "/Mantenimiento/FiltrarClientesTablaAsync",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "JSON",
    },
    "columns": [
    {
        "data": "Name"
    },
    {
        "data": "LatName"
    },
    {
        "data": "RucClient", //This could be null
        "defaultContent": ""
    },
    {
        "data": "Phone"
    },
    {                           
        "data": "Email", //This could be null
        "defaultContent": ""
    }
],
});
```

Is there any other solutions that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use render to process the data.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

```js
"columns": [
    {
        "data": "Name",
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
          if (!data) {
            return '';
          }
        }
        
    },
```

Comment: You could also: --  return data ||  ' ' --  instead of if condition

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of avoiding repetitive programming, I wrote a function called processNull.  Inside it, it will check if null is invalid, if it is, it'll return empty, if it isn't, then it'll render the full row.

```
function processNull(data) {
    if (!data) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}

var table = $('#tablaCliente').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": "5%",
        "targets": [0]
    },
    {
        "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",
        "targets": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }, ],
    "language":
    {
        "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":
    {
        "url": "/Mantenimiento/FiltrarClientesTablaAsync",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "JSON",
    },
    "columns": [
    {
        "data": "Name"
    },
    {
        "data": "LatName"
    },
    {
        "data": "RucClient", //This could be null
        "defaultContent": "",
        "render": processNull
    },
    {
        "data": "Phone"
    },
    {                           
        "data": "Email", //This could be null
        "defaultContent": ""
        "render": processNull
    }
],
});
```